# Libreoffice Calc 5.1.6.2 - How to match several rows using a single criteria?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

This is my first post and I'm very much a novice at spreadsheets, so please be gentle! I'm also conscious that I don't quite know enough to know how to ask the question properly, so please do excuse.

Note: I've made an example spreadsheet to illustrate my question, but I couldn't work out how to upload it here. If anyone could tell me how to do this (or whether it's not the done thing) that would be helpful. Since I couldn't upload the file I've described it below.

- I have a list of tasks in `A2:A25`, in strict ascending order. (1 to
  24, all rows are unique)
- I have a list of jobs in `B2:B25` that each
  task is associated with, but since sometimes the client changes the
  scope of the job I need to add in a new task, so the integers are not
  in order. I have 6 different job numbers for the 24 rows.
- I have a
  list of task names in `C2:C25`, which describe the task to be done. In
  my example there are 10 different types of task name for the 24 rows.
- In `F1` it says `RequestedJob#:`

My objective is to type in a job number in `G1`, and then for a list of all the task numbers associated with that job number to show up somewhere else on the sheet.

I'm familiar with using `IndexMatch`, so once I have that list I'll be able to extract all the task names. The gap in my knowledge that I'm trying to overcome is that `IndexMatch` will return a single value, whereas I want a list of entries.

Edit: I have tried and tried to get any later version of LibreOffice installed on my machine, but I just can't make it work. I think my operating system (Ubuntu 16.04) is likely at fault, but similarly a couple of weeks ago I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, but try as I may I couldn't get it to happen. All this to say, I'm stuck with LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 for the time being (until my friend helps me out with a new operating system), and I'm wondering if there's any way of achieving my goal within the capabilities of 5.1.6.2. I'm sorry that I can't make this easier, I just don't know how to get my system up-to-date!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! There is a fairly simple solution for your problem. It is based on the use of the [**TEXTJOIN()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_textjoin.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id581556228060864) function, inside which the desired values are selected from the raw data using the IF() function. Unfortunately, this solution is not available for you - the function appeared in Calc only [**in version 5.2**](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.2#New_spreadsheet_functions). Why don't you upgrade your office suite?

Comment: I am truly sorry that you are stuck with an old version of the office suite! Nevertheless, in this case, your task has several solutions - [**with macro**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/function-formula-to-filter/55461/5?u=johnsun) or [**without a macro**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/calc-macro-to-refresh-an-advanced-filter-or-formula-to-workaround/11601/6?u=johnsun).

Comment: Thank you ever so much for these suggestions, JohnSUN, as I've thought more about the problem I've realised that it would be an acceptable solution within my workflow to simply use AutoFilter rather than have a whole new list come up. Thanks again for the help, it provoked me to think around the problem!

Comment: You could try a vlookup